# Get list of Assert Constraints in FormType Extension in Symfony2.1

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to implement client side form validation with javascript and I'd like to use the Validation defined in the Entity or the Form by putting them in the fields data- property.

The problem is that I don't know nor find any information about how to get the constraints from within the FormType extension.

I thought that the FormBuilder should have access to the data as it is used to start validation, but there doesn't seem to be any method to retrieve constraints.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. It may not be the best, but serves for me.

I injected the Validator service into the FormTypeExtension.
Then I could do
 
`$this->validator->getMetadataFactory()->getClassMetadata($options['data_class']);`

I also had to change the service alias from "field" to "form" to get the data_class in options.

Hope this helps someone having the same problem.
If needed I can publish more details.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing - how do I find out on what property to run the validator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$validators = $form->getConfig()->getValidators();
```

on your form object

Comment: That returns an empty array :-(

Comment: Turns out that in Symfony 2.1 the validator list is not held in this property anymore and now validation is done using events. I don´t know how to get that info then

Comment: Thanks for trying :-) I'm currently looking to use the Validator class directly and make it parse the file. Will publish if I find a solution.